# Chrome Developer Bar: Reorder Elements

Tags: google-chrome

### Context

I am using Chrome. I am using the developer bar. It has the following order:

```
Elements Resources Network Scripts Timeline Profiles Audits Console
```

I am developing on a 13" MBP with iTerm taking the right half of the screen and Chrome taking the left half of my screen.

As a result, my Chrome bar looks like:

```
Elements Resources Network [DROPDOWN]
```

Now, I would like to reorder my Chrome bar to make it look like:

```
Elements Scripts Console [DROPDOWN]
```

instead.

I tried dragging stuff around, but was unable to.

### Question:

Is there some way I can re-order the elements on my Chrome developer bar?

Thanks!

Comment: Modify the source code to reorder, then recompile. Simple eh? :D

Comment: Too easy. I was hoping something that involved running chrome under gdb, then patching the binary at runtime.

Answer (score 4):

If you switch to the [Chrome Beta Channel](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/beta.html), you'll find that you can now drag-and-drop reorder the tabs in the Developer Tools as of version 47.

Comment: This is true. But as soon as you restart the browser, the order seems to reset. Pity.

Comment: Works fine now (Chrome 66). Order is kept even after killing Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you can use `Ctrl-1` to `Ctrl-9` (`Cmd-1` to `Cmd-9` in Mac) to toggle to a specific panel.

The resources are indeed stored in a file called `resources.pak`. It is a [binary format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10633357/how-to-unpack-resources-pak-from-google-chrome). If you look into it, you will see a JSON string specifying the relative ordering of the elements. Modify it using a hex editor, and you may get what you want. But since Google Chrome likes to auto-update by itself, you will probably need to re-apply your patch every couple of weeks.

[image]