# which files are need to be packaged with cefsharp winforms application

Tags: winforms, cefsharp

By using `CefSharp version 37.0.0` my `winforms` application is ready to submit in college but I am not getting which files (DLL,exe,pak) are need to be packaged along with project references. I already gone through this article https://github.com/cefsharp/cef-binary/blob/master/README.txt#L104-L106 but still confused in :

1. Is all .pak files (cef.pak,cef_100_percent.pak,cef_200_percent.pak,devtools_resources.pak and all files from locales folder) are used for `developer option`?
2. Can I make separate folder cefSharp reference files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to give a definitive complete answer, so: "It depends" on what your application uses. For `.pak` files e.g. if you are not using the DevTools in your application you can skip `devtools_ressources.pak` etc. similarly with languages and e.g. WebGL and other of the CEF .dll files.

See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/527 for a discussion already marked `faq-able!` it also contains info on setting path for `.pak` files. You can inspect the binaries etc. of the resulting WinForms application at https://github.com/rfgamaral/SlackUI/releases.

Moving .dll files around is not recommended/supported.

Also see this related SO entry: [What is the purpose of the cef.pak file in cefsharp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27399973/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-cef-pak-file-in-cefsharp)

Answer (score 1):

In theory, you can see a rundown of all the files here:
https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/src/aefb5ccce879f308f0bcc3ac719c86defe2f9715/tools/distrib/win/README.redistrib.txt?at=master

However, one thing they don't note about not including `cef.pak` (or disabling `pak` loading altogether) is that it will cause things like red scrollbars (at least on windows). I've found I need to include `cef_100_percent.pak` to avoid this.