# How to open/unpack the resources.pak file of Google Chrome

Tags: python, windows, google-chrome

I have read that the Python program can help in this case. When I try to open the resources.pak by the program I get the window "Specify file encoding" that asks me what is the current encoding of the file. If I leave **cp1251** or change to **utf8** and click **OK** I get the error

```
File path\to\resources.pak
Failed to Decode
```

I read the answer by the link [how to unpack resources.pak from google chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10633357/how-to-unpack-resources-pak-from-google-chrome?rq=1) but the link to the **data_pack.py** module is not actual. I found that module by the link https://github.com/Crystalnix/grit-i18n/blob/master/grit/format/data_pack.py but I don't know what exactly should I use it

Interesting in solution for Windows 7. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The following:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/metasmile/grit-i18n.git
$ cd grit-i18n/grit
$ python format/data_pack.py /usr/lib/chromium/resources.pak
```

works fine here.

Comment: that repo is no longer available

Comment: @BastiaanQuast Just tried it and it's there.