# Chrome 65 version resources.pak file unpack

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

In Chrome 65 version chrome change resources.pak file structure.
I use this answer before: [how to unpack resources.pak from google chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10633357/how-to-unpack-resources-pak-from-google-chrome)

But now how to change data_pack.py file to unpack new chrome resources.pak file? Need unpack resources.pak and save files.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what are you requirements. Do you need a Python-based solution, or you just want to unpack the files?

If you're only searching for a way to unpack a `.pak` file that works with the latest Chrome versions, you can use [chrome-pak-customizer](https://github.com/myfreeer/chrome-pak-customizer/releases). There are Windows binaries available in the Releases section or you can compile it yourself in your preferred platform. I just tested this approach in Chrome 68 (running on Windows 10 x64) and it worked.

Comment: Welcome to SO! This doesn't seem an answer at all. Please check [help].